# Is possible to set the same Django model to create many different types in elastic search with Haystack?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to create different document types in the same index but for the same model. For example:

I have a model costumer and a model employees related and I want to create a new document type employees in elastic search for each costumer in database

ES:9200/index/employee1
ES:9200/index/employee2
ES:9200/index/employeeN

Is possible to set the same Django model to create many different types in elastic search with Haystack?

Or maybe I want to create a weird data structure. What do you think?

Comment: What did you try so far? Imho it should be possible by declaring differently named classes which do return the same model in their `def get_model(self):` method.

Comment: Sure it's possible - you just define two indexes that use the same model.